# React not rendering components when using react-routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Im having an issue that components does not render when using react-router-dom.
The "home" has multiple components like, navbar, body, and a footer that I'm not able to render when I start to do routing.

this is the App.jsx:

```
import React from "react";
import Hero from './components/Hero'
import Featured from "./components/Featured";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import Tokens from "./components/Tokens";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';


function App(){
 return (
 <Router>
  <Route path="/">
       <Navbar/>
       <Featured /> 
       <Hero />
       <Footer />
  </Route>
  <Router>
    <Route path="/Tokens">
      {<Tokens/>}
    </Route>
  </Router>
</Router>
 )
}

export default App;
```

Navbar, featured, hero and footer are the components of my index/home page and Tokens is another component that fetch a crypto API. Everything works but the issue starts when routing :C

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom` do you have installed? You can run `npm list react-router-dom` from your project's directory and report back. Can you be more specific as to what the issue is (*other than "it's not working"*)? Are there any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that you are mixing react-router v5 and v6 styles.
You can use nested routes now, and the component to render for a route goes into the `element` attribute of the route.

[React Router Overview](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview)

From the documentation:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
        <Route index element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="teams" element={<Teams />}>
          <Route path=":teamId" element={<Team />} />
          <Route path="new" element={<NewTeamForm />} />
          <Route index element={<LeagueStandings />} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
```